# Probability distribution of a random variable - Interview

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, uniform-distribution

this question is from a interview a friend had and I was curious how to solve it.
The question is:

> I have two random variables, $a$ and $b$.
> $a=rand(1,100)$
> $b=rand(a,100)$
> The rand function generates a number within the range of the numbers in the parentheses, with equal probability for each number.
> How is $b$ distributed (what is its probability distribution function), and if I want b to be uniformly distributed between $a$ and $100$, just as a is uniformly distributed between 1 and $100$, what should I do?
> My aspiration is for them to be uniformly distributed; it's enough to make $b$ distributed more uniformly than it is now (I'm allowed to use any operator/function, etc.)?

My attempt:

> My approach to solving this involves trying to use a new function, $c=rand(1,a)$, so that they might complement each other. I attempted to use modulo operations and an if statement, meaning if the number is not within the range, then generate a new number.

Had a few other attempts, reached:

> $a$ distribute uniformly and $b$ not distribute as something "known", using the total of expectation value, but it is not clear.

Will be happy to receive help, thanks.

Comment: This seems like one of those interview questions where the first objective is not to solve the problem but to find out what the interviewer is asking. In this problem, once $a$ is known, the formula $\operatorname{rand}(a,100)$ gives a uniform distribution between $a$ and $100$ by definition; and what does it even mean to have a uniform distribution between $a$ and $100$ before $a$ is known?

Comment: @DavidK: It means that conditional on the value of $a$, the distribution of $b$ is uniform.

Comment: @DavidK what Joriki said is true, but still, my problem:.........
 If I check how $b$ is distributed generally, I will get something that is neither linear nor quadratic, for example, $p(b=100)= \frac1 {100}$ and  $p(b=1)=\frac 1 {10000}$, and it can be seen that the distribution is really non-uniform. Therefore, my aspiration is to correct it so that the probabilities of getting any number between $a$ and $100$ are approximately uniform (or better than what I currently have).

Comment: @joriki That's a reasonable guess as to what the interviewer meant (assuming they have any idea what they're asking), but then the solution is trivial: let $b=\operatorname{rand}(a,100)$ as initially suggested.

Comment: @DavidK: I’d interpret “How is $b$ distributed (what is its probability distribution function)” to refer to the marginal distribution of $b$. So I think the idea is that the marginal distribution of $a$ and the distribution of $b$ conditional on $a$ are given, and the marginal distribution of $b$ is to be determined. That would be consistent with `rand` being called a “function”, which suggest interpreting the two code-like lines as lines of code in a sequential programming language that first generate $a$ unconditionally and then generate $b$ using the previously generated value of $a$.

Comment: @Joriki That's also how I interpret “How is b distributed". But the second part of the question is "if I want $b$ to be uniformly distributed between $a$ and $100$, [...] what should I do?" If the answer to this question was not already given in the setup for the first part of the question, what does the question mean?

Comment: Your $b=rand(a,100)$ already  makes $b$ be uniformly distributed between $a$ and $100$ if you know $a$, i.e. the *conditional distribution* of $b$ is uniform.  If you want $b$'s *marginal distribution* to be uniform  on $(1,100)$ then there are various possibilities, three of which are $b=a$, $b=101-a$ and $b=rand(1,100)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Interviewer:***

Assume $a\sim U[0,1]\,,$ and conditional on $a\,,$ $$b\sim U[a,1]\,.$$
What is the unconditional distribution of $b\,?$

***Candidate*** (sweating):

\begin{align}
&\mathbb P\big\{b\le y\big\}=\int_0^1\mathbb P\big\{b\le y\,\big|\,a=x\big\}\,dx
=\int_0^1\frac{y-x}{1-x}1_{\{x\le y\}}\,dx=\int_0^y\frac{y-x}{1-x}\,dx\\[2mm]
&=-y\ln(1-x)\Big|_{x=0}^{x=y}+\Big[x+\ln(1-x)\Big]_{x=0}^{x=y}\\[2mm]
&=-y\ln(1-y)+y+\ln(1-y)\\[2mm]
&=y+(1-y)\ln(1-y)\,.
\end{align}
This is the unconditional CDF of $b\,.$

The PDF of $b$ is
$$
\frac{d}{dy}P\big\{b\le y\big\}=2-\ln(1-y)\,.
$$
The plot of it resembles the one in Joseph's answer.

To work out a possibility to turn this $b$ into a random variable
that is unconditionally uniform on $[c,1]$ where $c$ is fixed (I deliberately don't denote this by $a$)
one can use the well-known method to

- stick $b$ into its own
  CDF by which it produces a $U[0,1]$ variable and then
- stick that into the inverse CDF of the desired distribution.

The CDF of $U[c,1]$ is
$$
x\mapsto \frac{x-c}{1-c}
$$
which has inverse
$$
y\mapsto (1-c)y+c\,.
$$
Therefore,
$$
(1-c)\Big\{b+(1-b)\ln(1-b)\Big\}+c
$$
is uniform on $[c,1]\,.$

Comment: Hi, you solved parts A and B, but didn't say how to fix it ( part C ). That's my only question. That's exactly where I got stuck in the interview, trying to get B to be uniformly distributed over segment A,100

Comment: @Analysis_Complex_Study Do you mean you solved the above in an interview? To make $b$ uniformly distributed in $[a,1]$ we obviously just fix $a\,.$

Comment: Kurt G: sorry for answering after 7hours, went to sleep and just woke up........ by solved above, I mean I just needed help with this part:......  %%%%%%%%and if I want $b$ to be uniformly distributed between $a$ and $100$
, just as $a$ is uniformly distributed between $1$ and $100$
, what should I do? How to make $b$ distribute like that? I need to fix $b$ to make it happen, but I don't know how.

Comment: As I said: we choose the $a$ and keep it fixed and take $b=rand(a,100)\,.$

Comment: What does it mean by choosing $a$? sorry I am not understanding what you say correctly....... You already has $b$ like that

Comment: @Analysis_Complex_Study I am running out of ways to explain the simple thing to you how to construct $b$ that is uniformly distributed on between $a$ and $100\,.$ It is probably best if you run Joseph's little python code to see this in action. Case closed.

Comment: Hi, I asked my friend regarding this, he said I am not allowed to change $a$. He thought about it too, but the interviewer said to him it is not allowed.  If you don't know how to answer, then its all right, I see you are not in the mood anymore. Thanks though. ( That is why I did not understand, because he said it is not allowed to change $a$ and you did change it. )

Comment: @Analysis_Complex_Study Ex post it is hard to tell what that interviewer wanted to hear. BTW let me say that if that was a personal live interview I find the questions unusually complex. It is fine to ask candidates such questions but then they usually solve them at home within, say, a few days. Now back to the uniformity of $b\::$ perhaps that guy wanted to hear that if we stick $b$ into its own CDF it becomes uniform on $[0,1]\,.$ A well-known fact. Perhaps a hint what to do with $[a,1]\,.$

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 3):

Initially this problem seems a little confusing. I initially mistook $P(B=b|A=a)$ for $P(B=b)$ and thought $P(B=b)$ was already uniform! In such a situation to get a handle on the problem it can be very useful to try out some simple and extreme examples until you see if any patterns show up.

This is especially useful in an interview situation as it allows you to talk through the problem even when you are not sure how to solve it. In this case testing out a few simple and extreme examples can get us pretty much the whole way there. Lets see what we need to happen for $b$ to equal $100$:

$P(B=100) = P(B=100|A=a)P(A=a)$

So we get some value for $a$ with probability $\frac{1}{100}$, then there is a second probability for $b$ given the $a$ we drew. Let's try a case where $a = 100$:

$P(B=100) = 1 \cdot \dfrac{1}{100}$

i.e. we draw randomly from the range 100-100 so we must draw 100.

or when $a = 99$:

$P(B=100) = (0\cdot\dfrac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}) \cdot \frac{1}{100}$

In this case $B$ can be either $100$ or $99$ each with a half probability. We only care about the case where $b = 100$.

continuing this pattern on, we see:

$P(B = 100) = \frac{1}{100}\sum_{i=1}^{100} \frac{1}{i}$

i.e. gives the probability via the law of total probability:

$P(B=b) = \sum_{a\in A} P(B=b|A=a)P(A=a)$

Now, what about $P(B=99)$. If $a=100$, then $P(B=99)$ is zero. For $a=99$, the probability is $\frac{1}{2}$ (by the same logic that $P(B=100)$ is $\frac{1}{2}$ when $a = 99$). Indeed, it will follow the same pattern as $P(B=100)$, but starting one higher as the $a=100$ case is now excluded:

$P(B=99) =\frac{1}{100} \sum_{i=2}^{100} \frac{1}{i}$

Let's check the pattern at the other extreme, $P(B=1)$. In this case $a$ must equal $1$  because if it is any higher we cannot draw $1$ for $b$:

$P(B=1) = \frac{1}{100} \sum_{i=100}^{100} \frac{1}{i} = \frac{1}{100}\frac{1}{100}$
as expected.

So we can write the probability distribution for $B$ as:

$P(B=b) = \frac{1}{100} \sum_{i=(101 - b)}^{100} \frac{1}{i}, \ b = 1, 2, ... 100.$

#### Checking it is a valid probability distribution

Let's check this is a valid probability distribution that sums to 1 over the range $b \in [1, 100]$ (we can define it as $0$ otherwise).

$\sum_{k=1}^{100} P(B = k) = \frac{1}{100} \sum_{k=1}^{100} \sum_{i=(101 - k)}^{100} \frac{1}{i}$

Looking at the sum, it's a bit of a mess and I can't see any nice identities that work in this case. Again, let's expand the summation terms and see exactly what we are dealing with.

We saw earlier that for $P(B=100)$ the terms are $\frac{1}{1} + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + ... + \frac{1}{100}$. For $P(B=99$) we have all of these terms except $\frac{1}{1}$, this pattern continues until $P(B=1)$ has only 1 term, $\frac{1}{100}$. This means we have:

$1\cdot\frac{1}{1} + 2\cdot\frac{1}{2} + ... + 100 \cdot \frac{1}{100} = 100$

With the $\frac{1}{100}$ factor in front of that double summation, our sum ends up as $1$ as desired.

So, now we have the distribution of $B$ well specified.

Next, we want to make a transformation so the distribution of $B$ is uniform. One approach to be to rescale the probabilities of the distribution $P(B=b)$ based on the value of $a$, I will leave this up to you to play around with.

#### Visualising in python

The distribution of $B$ (with python code) looks like:

[image: distribution image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def dist(b):
    sum_ = 0
    for i in range(101-b, 101):
        print(i)
        sum_ += 1/i
    return sum_ * (1/100)

y = [dist(k) for k in range(1, 101)]
x = range(1, 101)

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.xlabel("b")
plt.ylabel("P(B=b)")
plt.show()
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, sadly I did not really understand :\
Thanks anyway!! ( my part was with part C, regarding the fix )

Comment: I see @Analysis_Complex_Study, I second everything Kurt G said in the other comments. In the discrete case as above, to get a feel for this you can ask - what do we need to do to the PMF $P(B=b)$ such that it becomes uniform? Because $P(B=b)$ is well specified, we could scale the output based on $b$. For every $b$ in range $1,...,100$ we would require $P(B=b) = 1/100$. So for example when $b$ equals 1 we multiply by $100$. $b=100$ divide by $\sum_{i=1}^{100} \frac{1}{i}$. I don't know why you'd ever do this in practice though. It's basically just saying 'let $P(B=b) = \frac{1}{100}$'.